# How to prevent caching of some piece of code in jsp?

Tags: jsp, aem

I have a JSP file in which I want some lines of code not to be cached. Is this possible?
Currently I am using:

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
```

This will work for a complete JSP, but I need it to affect only some lines in that file. 
Can we add a check for this? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Note that it's not JSP code that's cached: what you're doing is setting an HTTP header that tells the client browser how to cache the HTTP response. That's why you need to split that response into several parts if you want to cache them individually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is the response header in which we can set the cache as false/no. My problem was like this:
In home page there is one component in which the JSP is getting executed. Now I the functionality is that if I visit any other page, I'll set a cookie as visited in the browser, and one I go back to the home page, I read the cookie and display VISITED.

In my case the cookie is being set, but when I am reading is in JSP, it still shows UNVISITED.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to to achieve a partial caching behaviour with plain jsp's.
But there are two alternatives:

Try if for example the "Sling Dynamic Include" framework fits your needs.
https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Dynamic-Include
In this approach dynamic generated components are replaced by server side or edge side includes.
The ssi or esi includes are dynamically processed on every request.

The other approach is to use an ajax request to dynamically fetch the part that has to be dynamically rendered. To prevent the dynamically fetched resource from being cached just set the no-cahce header in that resources rendering script.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and the GIT link. We are using drag-drop for this component, so can't to sling include. But yeah the other approach seems a solution.

Again, thanks a ton for your help.